# Looping returned Objects of a computed Property in Table Rows VueJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, computed-properties

I want to loop through objects of a computed property in a bootstrap table row, but i do not seem to get any data rendered, but it's loaded on the console log.

And also display an incremental count of row numbers in ID column eg 1,2,3

See Table Code Below

```
<template><table class="table table-striped mb-0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Schedule of Areas</th>
            <th scope="col">Area</th>
            <th scope="col">Size</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr :v-for="Specification in  Specifications">
            <th scope="row">Incremental number based on available rows</th>
            <td> {{Specification.spec_title}}</td>
            <td>{{Specification.Area}}</td>
            <td>{{Specification.Size}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table></template>
```

See Vue Computed property code Below

```
<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
        this.getAllspecs('1');
    },
    computed: {
        Specifications: function() {
            return _.pickBy(this.allspecs.Specifications, function(u) {
                return u.status == 1 || ""
            })
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            allspecs: []
        };
    },
    methods: {
        getAllspecs: function() {
            axios.get("/api/getAllspecs")
            .then(function(response) {
                this.allspecs = response.data;
            }.bind(this));
        },
        created: function() {
            this.getAllspecs();
        }
    }};
  </script>
```

See Image of rendered objects

[image: See Image of rendered objects]

Any help will be greatly apreciated.

Comment: It's `v-for`, not `:v-for`.

Comment: It's still not working,

Comment: Do you see any warnings or errors in the console?

Comment: Ok had to run dev watch, its working now, could you help with rendering object id

Comment: `v-for` has built-in support for giving you the index. There's an example at https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for

Comment: Ok it works, Thanks for guidiance. Regard